# Force a bound text box in MS Access to store an empty string instead of NULL to a linked SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

**Repro**

1. Create an SQL Server table with a non-nullable text field, e.g.

   ```
    CREATE TABLE myTable (myIdentity INT IDENTITY(1,1), myText NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
   ```
2. Create an MS Access front-end database:

a. Attach the SQL Server table as an ODBC **linked** table.

b. Create a new form to modify the table: Set the form's RecordSource to the SQL Server table, set the form's Default View to "Continuous Form" and add a text box for each table field.

3. Open the front-end form and enter a few records.
4. Remove the content from the text box referencing the not-nullable text field in one of the rows and try to navigate away.

**Actual result**: Error message *"You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type"*.

**Desired result**: An empty string is stored in `myText` (instead of NULL, which is what Access tries to store).

---

What I have tried:

- I know of the workaround of manually entering two double quotes (`""`) into the text box (yes, it sounds crazy, but it really works - it won't store the quotes but an actual empty string). That's not a viable solution, since it's awkward to use for our users.
- Check and modify the `Value` property in the `BeforeUpdate` event of the text box: Won't be executed, since the error occurs *before* the event is raised.
- Check and modify the `Value` property in the `Change` event of the text box: Doesn't work, the `Value` property contains the original value, not the currently entered value.
- Check and modify the `Text` property in the `Change` event of the text box: Doesn't work, it's already an empty string instead of NULL.

How can I force Access to store an empty string instead of NULL through a bound text box?

Comment: why is the underlying field not nullable, if it's acceptable not to enter a value into it? Most consider that best practice is to store NULL when the field is empty, rather than an empty string.

Comment: @ADyson: There can be a variety of reasons, and NULL vs empty string for database values is a [hotly debated topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/32578/33843). :-) In my particular case, it's because "unknown" is not an acceptable value for the field, but "known empty" is.

Answer (score 2):

I would not do this. The problem is that SQL server does not have a system wide setting to say all nulls are to be "" (some systems like Oracle I do believe have this setting.

This is not really a debate about "" vs null.

The REAL problem is you as a developer want to decide that you not dealing with nulls. However, any left join query which is VERY common type of query will OFTEN be done.

So to get all customers with last invoice date, but some customers don't have invoices yet (so you use a left join). The query will thus return null values for the child table (invoice).

The result?

Well in your "general approach" your "general coding" and "general" application desing you will STILL HAVE to OFTEN deal with nulls in your VBA and your Access application.

So you trying to adopt a design approach in which you don't have nulls, but you WILL HAVE MANY cases in which data sets return nulls despite all tables NEVER saving null values.

If the above issue could be avoided by a "system wide" setting, then I would consider that all empty columns are a "" (zls, or what we call a zero length string).

Because you don't have such a system wide setting, then in much of your general coding approach, you now have to deal with both zls, and null columns in your code etc.

The result is a LOT MORE WORK. And what is MUCH worse is your general coding will over time "assume" "" strings, but then a whole slew of bugs and issues will crop up WHEN you hit the nulls in your over all application. And the reason you hit nulls is become of the SUPER common type of query that will be a LEFT join. So even with all tables never storing null values, you still have to deal with nulls in your code. Now you have to STILL deal with the original problem you attempted to avoid. And since your coding standard was to not deal with nulls, then you get TONS of bugs and issues when you finally hit the null wall.

As a result, you REALLY (but really really really) want to adopt a coding and design standard from day 1 for the OVERALL application design. Since you don't have a system wide choice for "" in place of nulls, then you are far better off to adopt the coding standard of:

For ANY empty column, assume it is null and design your application around this paradigm. After a few years of design, coding, and huge $$$ investments of time, you be able to stick to ONE coding standard and NOT two standards.

I have been migrating access applications to SQL server for 17 years now.

The "big" problem of course is in Access you have a design choice that works rather well (the developer CAN make the choice that all columns are "" in place of null). So if this was the original design assumption, then you may well consider that when using SQL server you also don't allow nulls. (however you will find "many" problems as your post shows).

Now of course if the original application always assumed nulls, then you are in rather great shape after migration of the tables to SQL server.

If you have a large existing application that did assume "" in place of nulls, then I would consider fixing the problem server side with triggers.

Bottom line:
You making a "big" design decision here that will fix in stone what you do for the many years in the future. If you CAN make this choice now, then without question assuming that any and all empty columns are null is a FAR better decision.

This decision is not based on some "" vs nulls argument or preference, but simply that the design and developer tool being used (Access as a front end to SQL server) works far better with nulls as the over all design choice due to the limitations of the tool choice here.

You will be forever committing to adding all kinds of extra silly code for controls on a simple form. With 25 or more text boxes on a form, you will now be forced to add code to every single text box. The coding cost of this choice will add up over the years, and increase developer costs - a cost you can 100% avoid by adopting the "simple" design choice that empty columns are always null.

At the risk of repeating myself, it really would be great if one could avoid nulls, and as noted some database systems have a "switch" and thus even those left joins without child records will in fact return "" in place of null when child records don't exist.

Because we don't have this system wide "switch", then as noted, your general overall coding approach in the application will STILL have to deal with null columns in the data with a surprising frequency. Since you can't avoid this issue, then flipping the design choice NOW means that all your coding approaches of assuming null will work for those cases that you can't avoid anyway.

The WHOLE idea of using Access as a front end to SQL server is the RAD ability. You will save 2-3 if not 5x the developer costs compared to using say vb.net, or some other desktop developer tool. So a $5000 project in Access will cost $25,000 in other tools.

You have to do as in Rome what the Romains do so to speak. For example you don't want to use a strong typed variable approach for say a scripting environment because the tools don't support that kind of design choice very well. So you "can" make such a choice but you then will be fighting against the tools you have.

So you have to adopt how the tool works best if you going to use that tool. This means as a developer I have to bite my lip, and do what the language and design tools like and want, not what I like or want as a developer.

I would think long and hard about your initial choice here, since you be stuck with that choice for years to come.

The choice of design tools here (Access + SQL server) is a great setup, but you have to "bend" as to how those tools really work together, or you be fighting your design choices for years.

Hands down:
Your design choice should be that any and all columns that are "empty" should be designed with the choice and assumption that all such columns are null when empty. The result is your general coding approach will work for forms, and SQL query and code you start writing over the years. You will hit lots of nulls in your code, so you might as well make that assuming now - you can't avoid this issue. When you start out, you go "hey", golly I don't have to deal with those stupid nulls - but as your project grows, all of a sudden, those null values will crop up with increasing frequency, and you now dealing with a issue that you attempted to avoid. Best to just always make this assuming, and your overall code etc. will work much better as a result.

Comment: In general, I agree with you, and all our applications that use solely an Access front-end have nullable text fields - we also don't want to constantly fight the technology we chose to use. :-) My question was really just about the special case where we need to deal with a non-nullable text field, which does occur every now and then for various reasons: a legacy database that we have to interact with, or, in this particular case, the requirement for the field to be part of a unique index, where only one "empty" entry is allowed (allowing NULL would make two distinct "empty" values possible).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to **check** the `Text` property (which is what is currently entered into the text box), but to **modify** the `Value` property (which is what will be written to the underlying field) in the `Change` event:

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_Change()
    If MyTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MyTextBox.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

This will make sure that whenever the text box contents are emptied, an empty string is written back to the database instead of NULL.

Note that this only helps when *modifying* rows with non-nullable fields. If your Access form supports *adding* rows, you also need to add a suitable non-NULL default value (for example, by setting the text box `Default Value` property to `=""`), since the Change event might not be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach is to fix this server side, when possible. Then, you can even just use the table to insert values, and you don't have to account for this quirk on every form and in every piece of code you write working with that table.

If you *really* want a `NOT NULL` column, just make it default to an empty string. Then Access won't have any trouble inserting into it, or modifying values:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (myIdentity INT IDENTITY(1,1), myText NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT (N''));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you've adapted `onChange Event` of the textbox. Please be advised, `onChangeEvent` only occurs when you physically change the content. Would not fire if you are using any macros or VBA to alter the content.

If you really want to avoid null being passed, you can use `Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)` with a combination of `nz(field,nullValue)`

i.e.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.[ColumnName] = Nz(Me.ColumnName, vbNullString) 'Making sure your column doesn't get null value passed
End Sub
```